Do Essosi rituals in Game of Thrones (R'hllor, Faceless Men, etc.) share similarities in handling corpses?
While browsing the A Song of Ice and Fire subreddit, I noticed a discussion highlighting similarities between two key scenes from Game of Thrones.
In the episode "High Sparrow" (S05E03), Arya, while training with the Faceless Men in Braavos, assists the Waif in stripping and cleaning corpses. This scene bears a strong resemblance to the ritual performed by Melisandre, a red priestess of R'hllor, to resurrect Jon Snow's corpse in the episode "Home" (S06E02).

The GIF above shows both scenes side by side, and they’re almost identical in how they handle the bodies, as if it were intentional.
One commenter suggested that these rituals might simply be the Essosi way of handling corpses. Given that both the Faceless Men and the faith of R'hllor originate from Essos, could these scenes suggest a shared cultural influence?
I'm wondering if this observation has any basis in the A Song of Ice and Fire books, which Game of Thrones is based on. Are there mentions of common corpse-related rituals among Essosi cultures (or maybe just the Faceless Men and the Faith of R'hllor) in the books?

What are the specific similarities between the scenes? If it's just ritually cleaning the corpse,  that's common in many real- life cultures across the world. Or are there particular similarities you noticed about how they do it?

@user56reinstatemonica8 The GIF I shared shows both scenes side by side, and they’re almost identical in how they handle the bodies, as if it were intentional. I’m curious if this is something that’s mentioned or has any basis in the books, where Essosi cultures, or maybe just the Faceless Men and the Faith of R'hllor, share a common ritual for handling bodies.

No, it doesn't reflect a cultural link and the two cultures are consistently presented as very different, it's more likely a stylistic storytelling throwback, to try to present the scene as a mournful funeral scene (with a twist), and not just casually magically resurrecting a popular and plot-crucial character.
The only specific death rite of the Red Priests hinted at in the books is very different:

"...I filled my mouth with fire and breathed the flames inside him, down his throat to lungs and heart and soul. The last kiss it is called, and many a time I saw the old priests bestow it on the Lord's servants as they died. I had given it a time or two myself, as all priests must. But never before had I felt a dead man shudder as the fire filled him, nor seen his eyes come open"
--Thoros telling Arya Stark how he bought Beric Dondarrion back to life, in A Storm Of Swords

Most of the similarities in the scenes seem to be stylistic similarities in the depiction of carefully, dutifully washing a corpse. Most of the actual acts seen (except the throwing hair into a fire, probably) are common in the real-life duties of funeral or mortuary professionals (or in many cultures by friends and family):

Cleaning the body: Funeral home staff will typically clean the body using warm water and a mild soap or disinfectant solution. They will pay special attention to areas such as the face, hands, and hair, ensuring that all traces of dirt, oil, or other substances are removed.
--EverLoved.com, "How do Funeral Homes Prepare a Body for a Funeral?"

As for general parallels between Bravos and Mel's home town of Asshai, there are very few. Bravos is presented in the books as something like the renaissance-era city-state of Venice in its prime:  well-engineered canals, wealthy, sophisticated financial industry (not just the Iron Bank, one of Arya's marks is a dishonest insurance broker), fabulously-dressed ruffians dueling with rapiers... Asshai and the Shadowlands, meanwhile, are at the opposite edge of the continent and presented as a mix of high-fantasy "land of dark magic" tropes mixed with middle-ages Europeans' wildest orientalist fantasies about the mysteries of Asia. Remember the mysteriously-masked Asshai shadowbinder Quaithe who briefly appeared in Season 2 in Qarth, muttering dark prophecies? (I don't blame you if you don't, the writers didn't...).
The Rhllor religion worship light and associate death with darkness and the ultimate-evil "Great Other", while the Many-Faced God followers see death and darkness as a blessing. But these differences don't mean they can't both wash corpses in a normal way (with a bit of added fire-woo for the fire priests).
There are undoubtedly stylistic similarities in how those scenes are filmed, but I don't see any reason to read anything more into it than a simple throwback to show how dutifully, professionally and carefully Mel was treating this corpse.  She didn't at this point expect him to come back to life, she was simply sombrely doing her priestly duties, like Arya and the Waif did (and also like the sisters of the seven did with Jon Arryn way back in Season 1).
If there's any significance to the similarities,  I think it's storytelling not lore, to downplay viewers' expectations, presenting the scene less as a blatant "and now of course they triumphantly use the magic plot armour to bring the hero back to life!", colouring it more like "this is a preparation for a normal, sombre funeral, like we've seen before... or is it?".
